# Best term in worldwide English for a "monthly cost"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need the most accurate, known, day-to-day term to express a cost that is paid by a customer on a month to month basis in order to use a service. E.g: Netflix, Internet, Cable TV... If possible, a single word expression is better!

So far, I could only come up with "monthly cost" and "monthly fee".

Comment: My intuition is that "monthly cost" and "monthly fee" and maybe "monthly price" are the most standard expressions for this. They are certainly *very* common.

Comment: In Portuguese, we have `Mensalidade` which means `something that happens in a per month basis` but I could not find a similar single word expression. Do you happen to know anything similar in English?

Comment: Maybe some people use the Latin phrase *per mensem* that way, or perhaps just "monthly" (as a noun, as in "I have to pay my monthly"). But you asked for the "most accurate, known, day-to-day" expression, which is certainly "monthly cost" or one of its variants.

Comment: Can you believe it? There are two persons who flagged saying this question is not about the English language within the scope defined. What? This is a plain question asking for a financial term that connotes "monthly". To antagonise you guys, I'll upvote this question.

Comment: "monthly [fixed] fee/charge/subscription" are very common;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that ''monthly X'' is absolutely standard, where X varies according to the context. Off the top of my (British English) head, for a service like Netflix, *cost* would be slightly better, as 'fee' feels slightly punitive, and so would be more often used to refer to the cost of something that is regarded as a basic commodity. So

''I pay a monthly fee of £10 for my line rental''

would fit, as this is something that (in the UK at least) is a basic charge that one pays on top of e.g. phone bills, internet connection, cable TV etc. Similarly, you might say

''I pay my golf club a monthly fee of £50 for membership, and £100 each time I use the golf course''

You'd always use *fee* for a professional service from an individual like a lawyer. Then there are other situations where X would supplant *cost* as something more specific e.g. monthly *rent*, monthly *charge* (particularly for a bank, although you could also use *fee* for that...), etc.

But monthly X is completely standard, in particular I never see the latin *per mensum* used, in contrast to *per annum* which is still quite common.

Comment: It would be great if you could find sources for your claim. This is a subjective answer. You could improve it by adding resources that substantiate the usage.

Comment: Substantiate the usage of common language?  It is subjective, to a degree, but then the OP asked about "worldwide English", which is ostensibly non-existent for this question.  American English, British English, and Australian English all have words that are used similarly, but with different inherent or implied meanings.  Honestly, I find this to be an excellent answer.

Comment: @JesseWilliams please have a look at the help center to finally find out what this site is about.

Comment: Helmar, I understand the principles. But now the answer is upvoted and accepted, so clearly others find the answer useful, including the OP. People getting answers and help they need is the CORE purpose of all SE sites.

Answer (score -1):

The expenses which are per unit time are called **running costs** (for a business or a household), they may be paid by other time chunks than months (weekly, fortnightly, quarterly...). Depending of what type of expenses you are considering, maybe the word **utility bills** can fit and have a more direct meaning related to households:

> The term utilities can also refer to [a] set of services (...) consumed by the public: electricity, natural gas, water, and sewage. Broadband internet services (both fixed-line and mobile) are increasingly being included within the definition. 
>   (Wikipedia)

Comment: Downvote without comment is unhelpful.

Comment: At a guess, the first downvote is because you haven't addressed the fact that the OP wants a term which denotes *monthly*. The second downvote is definitely for this reason.

Comment: @AndyT: if you had wanted to ask the question without having the "running cost" phrase in mind, how would you have described the concept of paying continuously rather than once? Choosing a (commonly used) unit of time seems quite natural for this.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions "month" in a) the title, b) the question body, c) a comment. If he had wanted a generic term, rather than a monthly term, I'm sure he could have written "a cost that someone has to pay again and again, e.g. once a month or once a year".